# Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: window.scrollTo is not a function (Meteor application)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to run a Meteor.js application using scrollTo(0,0) to get each of my iron-routes to go to the top of the page:

client/lib/router.js:

```
    Router.route('/services', {
        name: 'services',
        template: 'services',
      onAfterAction: function () {
        scrollTop();
      }  
    });

Router.route('/inquiry', function() {
    this.layout('inquiry');
    onAfterAction: function () {
      scrollTop();
  } 
});

    function scrollTop() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
```

Console error:

```
meteor.js:880 Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: window.scrollTo is not a function
    at scrollTop (http://localhost:3000/app/client/lib/router.js?942b5705d17b5d736fe545b9dd17f3ea42238776:45:12)
    at Router.route.onAfterAction (http://localhost:3000/app/client/lib/router.js?942b5705d17b5d736fe545b9dd17f3ea42238776:17:9)
    at RouteController.runHooks (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:265:7)
    at RouteController._runRoute (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:551:8)
    at Function.Route.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:848:18)
    at route (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:705:11)
    at boundNext (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:418:31)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:22
    at dispatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:442:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:385:13
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second route is incorrect, you've mixed the functional style setup with the object style of i-r.

```
Router.route('/inquiry', function() {
    this.layout('inquiry');
    onAfterAction: function () {
      scrollTop();
  } 
});
```

Should be:

```
Router.route('/inquiry', {
  template: 'inquiry',
  onAfterAction: function () {
    scrollTop();
  }
});
```

Comment: the only thing is, I have a layout that I am using for all of my routes, but I don't want it used on the inquiry route.  If I do it this way, then it will still inherit the layout on the inquiry route

Comment: also, despite that change, I am still getting the error

Comment: You might find [this guide](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Except the syntax bug like @Michel said, you might need to have

```
onAfterAction: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
        scrollTop();
    }
}
```

to ensure that the template is rendered

Comment: I made this change, I am getting the same error output.

Comment: Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: window.scrollTo is not a function

Comment: i don't think window is available at the time page loaded. can you `console.log(window)` in the`scrollTop` to see that is printed out?

Answer (score 0):

This error seemed to go away when I used .scroll(0,0) instead of .scrollTo(0,0).  I am not sure why this is the case, but the error is gone and the functionality is there using scroll